# Image not changing on ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader, android-lazyloading

I am using universal image loader for showing Image on Imageview

First i load three Images on four Imageview, Loading sucessfully

```
          imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[0], holder.thumbImage1, options);
         imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[0], holder.imgProperty, options);
         imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[1], holder.thumbImage2, options);
         imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[2], holder.thumbImage3, options);
```

after That i  click on `holder.thumbImage1` and want to changed image on `holder.imgProperty`

```
 holder.thumbImage2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                imageLoader.displayImage(url1, holder.imgProperty, options);
            }
        });
```

but image is not changing and also i am not getting any error

Please help me how i can fix this issue.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You're saying you want to click on thumbImage1, but your `clickListener` is on thumbImage2. Is it just an error here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `notifyDataSetChanged` :

```
holder.thumbImage2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               imageLoader.displayImage(url1, holder.imgProperty, options);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       });
}
```

Comment: Try to call `holder.imgProperty.requestLayout()` before calling `displayImage`

Comment: 'holder.imgProperty.requestLayout()' Also not working

Comment: I am working on this topic past two day but did not solve this issue, Please suggest me new and easy way t solve this problem

Comment: i think problem occur holder.imgProperty  in Onclick

Comment: Try to debug your code and see if the `onClick` is fired